My Microsoft Word VBA Copy/Paste Script Isn't Working Properly
I'm trying to use Microsoft Word VBA to do the tedious work of copying/pasting text from about 200 word documents into a template in the sections they belong. I've been able to get it to run, but not been able to get it to detect the content that I want it to copy/paste. I'm very new to programming and have a lot to learn. Can someone review this and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here are two docs to help show what I need done. The template that information will be pasted into. Example of doc that info will be copied from.
Sub AutomatePolicyCreationWithSubfolders()
    Dim sourceFolder As String
    Dim destFolder As String
    Dim templatePath As String
    Dim subFolder As Variant

    ' Set the folder paths
    sourceFolder = "C:\Users\bfund\OneDrive\Desktop\Policy Work\Policy Work\Data to be Copied From\"
    destFolder = "C:\Users\bfund\OneDrive\Desktop\Policy Work\Policy Work\New Policies\"
    templatePath = "C:\Users\bfund\OneDrive\Desktop\Policy Work\Policy Work\Template\Liberty University Policy Template 2024-04-23 - SFS.docx"

    ' Loop through each main subfolder
    For Each subFolder In Array("Grants", "Loans", "Loans\Processor 2\Private Loan Procedures")
        ' Call the recursive function to process files in all subfolders
        ProcessSubfolders sourceFolder & subFolder, destFolder & subFolder, templatePath
    Next subFolder

    MsgBox "Process Completed!"
End Sub

Sub ProcessSubfolders(ByVal sourcePath As String, ByVal destPath As String, ByVal templatePath As String)
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim subfolder As Object
    Dim file As String
    Dim sourceDoc As Document
    Dim targetDoc As Document
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim titleText As String
    Dim purposeText As String
    Dim proceduresText As String
    Dim foundPurpose As Boolean

    ' Initialize FileSystemObject to iterate through folders
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Attempt to get the folder; if it fails, provide feedback
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sourcePath)

    ' Loop through all subfolders
    For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
        ' Recursively process each subfolder
        ProcessSubfolders subfolder.Path, destPath & "\" & subfolder.Name, templatePath
    Next subfolder

    ' Process all files in the current folder
    file = Dir(sourcePath & "\*.docx")
    Do While file <> ""
        ' Open the source document
        Set sourceDoc = Documents.Open(sourcePath & "\" & file)

        ' Open the template document
        Set targetDoc = Documents.Open(templatePath)

        ' Initialize variables
        titleText = ""
        purposeText = ""
        proceduresText = ""
        foundPurpose = False

        ' Extract content from the source document
        For Each para In sourceDoc.Paragraphs
            If para.Range.Font.Name = "Cambria (Headings)" And para.Range.Font.Size = 26 Then
                titleText = para.Range.Text
            ElseIf para.Range.Font.Name = "Cambria (Headings)" And para.Range.Font.Size = 12 And Left(para.Range.Text, 8) = "Purpose:" Then
                purposeText = para.Range.Text
                foundPurpose = True
            ElseIf foundPurpose Then
                proceduresText = proceduresText & para.Range.Text & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next para

        ' Paste the "Policy Title" text into the correct locations in the template
        If titleText <> "" Then
            With targetDoc.Content.Find
                .Text = "Add Policy Title"
                .Replacement.Text = titleText
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With

            With targetDoc.Content.Find
                .Text = "Policy Title"
                .Replacement.Text = titleText
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        End If

        ' Paste the "Purpose" text into the "Policy Rationale" section in the template
        If purposeText <> "" Then
            With targetDoc.Content.Find
                .Text = "Policy Rationale"
                If .Execute Then
                    .Parent.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                    .Parent.InsertAfter purposeText & vbCrLf
                End If
            End With
        End If

        ' Paste the remaining content under "Procedures"
        If proceduresText <> "" Then
            With targetDoc.Content.Find
                .Text = "Procedures"
                If .Execute Then
                    .Parent.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                    .Parent.InsertAfter proceduresText
                End If
            End With
        End If

        ' Save the new document in the corresponding subfolder in "New Policies"
        fileName = Replace(file, ".docx", "_Policy.docx")
        targetDoc.SaveAs2 destPath & "\" & fileName

        ' Close the documents
        sourceDoc.Close False
        targetDoc.Close False

        ' Get the next file in the folder
        file = Dir
    Loop

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error accessing folder: " & sourcePath & vbCrLf & "Error: " & Err.Description
    Resume Next
End Sub

I tried making the script less strict when finding content to copy. For example, look for any paragraph with "Purpose:", and to consider any text in a font size 24 or larger as a possible title. This didn't seem to fix the problem. I'm sure it's something obvious, but I've been losing my mind for like 45 minutes now.

In VBA you don't need to use the untyped CreateObject function - you can do Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject instead, which preserves type-information (i.e. it gives you intellisense).

"but not been able to get it to detect the content that I want it to copy/paste." - okay, but you haven't told us what content you're wanting to copy either... so we can't really help you until you do.

Without access to a a sample of the type of document you're trying to copy from, or a screenshot, it's difficult for anyone to suggest what the problem might be.

You really should document the problem with examples of text you want to find and based on what properties you capture them. With only a piece of code we cannot help you as your code on itself is working.

@Dai I've added two docs that show what I'm trying to copy and paste.

@TimWilliams sorry about that! I've added these docs that show what I'm trying to do https://docs.google.com/document/d/1p6OloP3h2ejjlrjCaMWV1AN4zN5B7OBT/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107487781772992428622&rtpof=true&sd=true   https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nbs9KlfxwbmIGAP8g8iDNgnwNfE5WCjC/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107487781772992428622&rtpof=true&sd=true

@Aldert I should have! Sorry about that. I added the examples: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nbs9KlfxwbmIGAP8g8iDNgnwNfE5WCjC/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107487781772992428622&rtpof=true&sd=true
